# HTML code is not picking up the image tag

Tags: html, css

I have the following code in html, but for some reason its not picking up the image:

```
 <img src="../img/bunny2.png" width="21" height="16" border="0"/>
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: did you mean to miss the open tag symbol '<' ?

Comment: The question and snippet lack context.  It could be that you're missing the '<' symbol, or it could be that you're pointing to the wrong relative location of the image.

Comment: It is almost definitely to do with your filepath, where is the current file located in respect to the file image location? same folder? one folder deeper?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `<` at the beging of the `img` tag code.

```
<img src="/img/bunny2.png" width="21"  height="16" border="0"/>
```

Basic example http://jsfiddle.net/x8dSP/3016/

**EDITED**

Since you've edited your answer - It is almost definitely to do with your filepath